# Thunderbird Mail continually repeats authentication with Gmail

Tags: thunderbird

Trying to set up existing Gmail IMAP accounts (with 2 factor on) in Thunderbird version 68.10.0 (64-bit) running on Hera 5.1.. Inputting account name and password, then the numbers from the authenticator app. I have ten Gmail accounts. Each time, they all repeat, asking for user name, password and numbers, over and over. I tried turning off 2 factor and using the setting for "less secure apps" in one of my accounts, but the problem persisted. Then I changed OAUTH to plain password in Thunderbird, but it still asks for password each time I try to fetch email from that account. I've tried the recommended setting in about:config also with no success. It seems that Thunderbird, at least this version, cannot work with Gmail. I was hoping to import my Thunderbird profile from Windows, which has a lot of offline folders that I want to keep. Is there a solution for this? Or is there another email client of the capability level of Thunderbird (multiple accounts and a unified inbox at the least) that is Gmail friendly? I also liked the automatic backup addon that Thunderbird has. BTW I hate Google. Big time!

Answer (score 1):

I was having similar problems and tried installing Thunderbird 68.?.? on a Zorin distribution. This worked with a Gmail account. So, the problem would appear to be an Elementary OS one.

Comment: It turned out to be the version of Thunderbird that EOS has in their repository.